# keytool: import certificate chain from several .cer files

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keytool

Our IT dept gave me 4 .cer files, that constitute certificate chain: thawte_root.cer->intermediate1_pem.cer->intermediate2_pem.cer->our_company.cer.

I need to sign some code (via jarsigner) using our_company.cer.

Therefore, I have to create a keystore, containing our_company.cer and the chain-to-the-root.

I've tried to simply concatenate these 4 files into one using notepad and then import the resulting file, but keystore imports only the first one and when I try to launch jarsigner, I get

```
"jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: our_company. our_company must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain."
```

I get the same message when I import only our_company.cer or when I import each certificate one-by-one.

So the question is: how can I import 4 certificates as one chain?

Thanks in advance. Vitaly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Chain all certificates into one file (order is sub to root)
   `cat intermediate2_pem.cer intermediate1_pem.cer thawte_root.cer > chain.cer`
2. Run this openssl command
   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in our_company.cer -inkey private.key -out company.p12 -name company -CAfile chain.pem -caname sub2 -caname sub1 -caname root -chain`
3. Create keystore
   `keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore company.keystore -srckeystore company.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias company`

Your keystore will be ready (pick a password and type it in for all circumstances). You will also need to have your `private.key` ready.

See [this link](https://sebworks.com/java-keystore-generation/) for more detailed information.

Comment: Could ypu please edit your answer to reflect that Step 1 outputs chain.cer whether Step 2 searches for chain.pem.
Probably, all certs in Step 1 should be in pem format, otherwise there is an error "unable to load certificates" during Step 2 (here is the explanation: https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/unable-to-load-certificates-when-using-openssl-to-generate-a-pfx)

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, code signing works using [public-key encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). To sign code you need to have a private key, and clients wanting to use your code must trust the corresponding public key.

The CER files that you have are certificate files corresponding to the public keys. When you import them with `keytool -importcert` without the corresponding private keys, they are imported as trusted certificates. (See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_importcert) for more details. Depending on your system setup, you probably don't need to import them all - you probably already trust the Thawte certificate, for example.)

Since you want to sign code as YourCompany, you will need the private key corresponding to our_company.cer - I suppose your IT department can provide this, since it will have been used to generate the Certificate Signing Request sent to Thawte. If they are not willing to pass this on to you you will need to generate your own private/public key pair using `keytool -genkeypair`, generate a CSR with `keytool -certreq` and send it to your IT department who can then issue you a certificate. The final chain of trust in this case would be thawte_root.cer->intermediate1_pem.cer->intermediate2_pem.cer->our_company.cer->your_department.cer